# Is my response correct?

Tags: greetings

My recruiter started his email with phrase : I hope you're doing well.

Is it correct to reply : Thanks, I am doing well and I hope you're doing well too.

Comment: No, it's just a polite formula. Ignore it.

Comment: This is an issue of pragmatics and cultural niceties and is as on target (on-topic)  as asking about a proper response to the question *How are you?*

Answer (score 1):

The *grammar* of your response is correct. However, pragmatically the question by your recruiter is quite possibly  a polite formula, as Mike has hinted. The recruiter probably has little actual  interest in your wellness, except as it might directly affect your ability to do your job. Therefore, you can  consider the sentence as one that needs no response. Instead, you should get right to the matter that you want to tell the recruiter.